# Java Programming - Coding based on flowchart

Tags: java

I am new to programming and would appreciate any experts to provide suggestions.

Based on the given flowchart, am I on the right track?

How do I make improvement to my code to ensure robustness?

**Flowchart**

[image: click here for the flowchart]

**Code**

```
    // r is row, c is column
    int r = 1, c = 1;
    
    do { 
        if (r <= 4)
        {  
          if (c <= 10)
          {
              System.out.print("*");
              c += 1;
          }
          else {
              r += 1;
              c = 1;
              System.out.println();
          }
        }
        else {
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }while (c != 12);
```

**Output**

```
**********
**********
**********
**********
```

Comment: One thing which I would suggest, as it is a *vitally important point* to get acquainted from the beginning, is to name your variables reasonably and let your code speak about itself, so that it is understandable. No one would understand what is `r` and `c`; whereas, `row` and `column` would make much more sense and you won't need a redundant comment then. The naming is one of the most important problems programmers encounter, so, getting good habits from the beginning is a good idea.

Comment: I assume you added `c!=12`just to make sure it stops even if you made a bug in the logic of c. Normally c will never become 12. In such a case I prefer `c>=12` so even when your bug results in c getting a higher value, it will stop.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Hi, thank you for your reply. Does this actually mean that my code is correct based on the flowchart? Because I actually added "**System.out.println();**" in the else statement.

Comment: Your diagram does not mention CR/LF so you should not add a `println` resulting in a single row of `*`s.

Comment: The code is correct and does what it is meant to do according to the flowchart (arguably you shouldn't use the println(), because the flowchart doesn't tell you to, but the fact that it mentions rows and columns leads me to believe the intent is to have it). An alternative would be to implement it with loops

Comment: Also, you have one redundant print statement on line 15.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri, I understand from the flowchart, there is no println statement, however my initial output was "****************************************". It was only after putting the println statement, the output was only reflected as shown above. Is there something wrong with the flowchart?

Answer (score 2):

```
while (c != 12);
```

The flow chart doesn't have this condition.

Notice how your `if (r <= 4)` statement is directly nested in the `do...while`. This means you can reduce to a single `while`:

```
while (r < = 4) {
    ...
}
```

Similarly `c <= 10` should be implemented as a loop instead of just an `if`.

The flow chart doesn't say to do start a new line like you do with `System.out.println();`. So taken literally, this line is incorrect. However, I suspect the flow chart omitted this detail and is in error.

Answer (score 1):

According to the algorithm proposed, its code is seen to follow or comply with the guideline.
Your code looks great, it just tries to name the variables in a more similar way to what you are trying to replicate.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to shorten the number line of coding.

```
    int row = 1, column = 1;
    
        while (row <= 4)
        {
          if (column <= 10) {
              System.out.print("*");
              column += 1;
          }
          else {
              row += 1;
              column = 1;
              //System.out.println();
          }
        }
```